# What is the preferred way of checking multiple pointers against nullptr?

Tags: c++, nullptr

Assume that I've multiple pointers, and I want to check them against `nullptr` before dereferencing them. What is the proper way of doing it?

I believe that the safest solution is as below. But, I don't want my code to get crowded with `nullptr` keywords.

```
int *ptr_0, *ptr_1 /* and so on.. */;

/* .. some ugly operations .. **/

if((nullptr == ptr_0) || (nullptr == ptr_1))
    std::cout << "One of them was null!" << std::endl;
else 
    std::cout << "All clear sir!" << std::endl;
```

At first, I thought that using bitwise-and would solve it. Then, I realized that it has a small bug in it. The code below fails if the pointer objects were like `ptr_0 = 0xFFFF0000;` and `ptr_1 = 0x0000FFFF;`

```
int *ptr_0, *ptr_1 /* and so on.. */;

/* .. some ugly operations .. **/

if(std::uintptr_t(ptr_0) & std::uintptr_t(ptr_1)) 
    std::cout << "One of them was null!" << std::endl;
else 
    std::cout << "All clear sir!" << std::endl;
```

So, do you have any better solution to that?

Comment: How are you getting these pointers?  If you change that interface to take references, there would be no reason to check for null values.  Also, why not use an array or vector of these pointers?  Then you can use an [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to run through the whole collection and see if any are null.

Comment: The second solution is not idiomatic C++ code, and in my opinion should be avoided.  I prefer `if (!ptr_0 || !ptr_1) ...`

Comment: What's wrong with he first attempt? It is descriptive and fast.

Comment: I'm old enough for `if (!ptr0 || !ptr1 ||... )` or `if (!(ptr0 && ptr1 && ...)`. You might be, too. (On a side note: once you do encounter a null pointer, you're going to curse yourself for not checking them individually and making it harder for yourself to determine which one was the culprit.)

Comment: `ranges::any_of(std::initializer_list{p1, p2}, [](auto* p){ return p == nullptr; }`? but `(nullptr == ptr_0) || (nullptr == ptr_1)` seems fine to me.

Comment: Wouldn't a function template and fold expression do what you want?  Something like `template<typename... T> bool all_non_null (T*... p){ return (p && ...); }` and use as `if (all_non_null(p1, p2, p3, p4) { ...` .  Not sure it saves you much though.

Comment: @G.M. Looks like the best solution is to use the logical-and operator. I implemented it inline as the fold expression doesn't work in C++11. Thanks for the suggestion. If you could write an answer, I would accept it.